# How to use a conditional on a column of vectors in mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I tried to write this code, but the conditional check the entire column (and not row by row) :

```
value <- c("A","B","C")
list.value <- list(c("A","B"),c("A","C"),c("C","B"))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(value, list.value))

data %>% mutate(test = ifelse(value %in% unlist(list.value), "YES", "NO"))
```

I am trying to check if a value is in a corresponding vector stored in a column.

Comment: You could use `rowwise`: `data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(test = ifelse(value %in% unlist(list.value), "YES", "NO"))`

Comment: It might be more efficient to use vectorisation instead of `rowwise()`: ``data |> mutate(test = ifelse(`%in%`, value, list.value), "YES", "NO"))``